# How to show function result in Pop up window

Tags: c#, bootstrap-modal

I use Bootstrap Modal to show Pop up window by click a button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In my project, I have a onclick function for that button which will show a graph. This is written in C# in behind.

Comment: I think you have to skip the show graph button `click function` and with bootstrap modal event `show or shown` graph can be showed in modal when modal open

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I didnt quite understand show or shown graph. Can you write a sample code for me? really appreciate that

Comment: you can find bootstrap modal events, http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events, show n show, hide and hidden, these events triggered  when modal open (show & shown) and when modal closed (hide and hidden) so you want to show the graph in modal, you can just put the code inside the event lets, say `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {// what ever here will be triggered when modal will be about to show})` or `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {// what ever here will be showed when modal fully opened})` hope it explains, cannot put this in answer, right :)

Comment: @Shehary I modified my code in the question. Is that what you mean? it still doesn't work. It will show a pop up window, but the result graph is not shown in that window. Thanks for your help. I'm a bigineer in web Developing. Applogize if I misunderstood your answer